# Munkres' Topology, 2nd edition: Definition on pp. 81--82, Chapter 2: How is this collection a basis?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $K$ denote the set of all numbers of the form $1/n$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, the set of all positive integers, and let $\mathcal{B}''$ denote the collection of all the (finite) open intervals $(a,b)$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a< b$, on the real line along with  all sets of the form $(a,b) \setminus K$.

Then how do we know that the collection $\mathcal{B}''$ is a basis for some topology on $\mathbb{R}$ according to the definition given by Munkres on page 78 at the beginning of sec. 13?

I mean how to verify that $\mathcal{B}''$ satisfies the following condition?

If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

1. Note that $((a,b)\setminus K)\cap((c,d)\setminus K)=((a,b)\cap(c,d))\setminus K$.
2. What can you say about the intersection of two finite intervals?